# Running Open-Liberty as a non root user

Tags: linux, permissions, startup, open-liberty

We are trying to run an Open Liberty on a Red Hat server 7.9, however, the service will not start.

Systemd script which is starting the application is giving the following message:

```
OPENLP.service - IBM WebSphere Application Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/OPENLP.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2022-05-04 20:09:10 +04; 8min ago
  Process: 38704 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/OPENLPNode.sh stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 38731 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/OPENLPNode.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 38731 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 04 20:09:10 linux-c java[38743]: IBM Java[38743]: JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using '/tmp/javacore.20220504.200910.38743.0002.txt' in response to an event
May 04 20:09:10 linux-c OPENLPNode.sh[38731]: JVMDUMP030W Cannot write dump to file //javacore.20220504.200910.38743.0002.txt: Permission denied
May 04 20:09:10 linux-c OPENLPNode.sh[38731]: JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using '/tmp/javacore.20220504.200910.38743.0002.txt' in response to an event
May 04 20:09:10 linux-c OPENLPNode.sh[38731]: JVMDUMP010I Java dump written to /tmp/javacore.20220504.200910.38743.0002.txt
May 04 20:09:10 linux-c java[38743]: IBM Java[38743]: JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Snap dump using '//Snap.20220504.200910.38743.0003.trc' in response to an event
May 04 20:09:10 linux-c OPENLPNode.sh[38731]: JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Snap dump using '//Snap.20220504.200910.38743.0003.trc' in response to an event
May 04 20:09:10 linux-c OPENLPNode.sh[38731]: JVMDUMP030W Cannot write dump to file //Snap.20220504.200910.38743.0003.trc: Permission denied
May 04 20:09:10 linux-c OPENLPNode.sh[38731]: JVMDUMP010I Snap dump written to /tmp/Snap.20220504.200910.38743.0003.trc
May 04 20:09:10 linux-c OPENLPNode.sh[38731]: JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "traceassert", detail "".
May 04 20:09:10 linux-c systemd[1]: Started IBM WebSphere Application Server.
```

Any idea as to what might be causing the above?

Regards,
Nick Baldacchino

Comment: If you're not getting any of those javacores, you can set IBM_JAVACOREDIR
 in the native environment in your systemd unit to point it somewhere writable.

Comment: Are you sure that user that starts Liberty has a write access to the Liberty folder? e.g. to create message.log file. Do you see that file created?